# Error en ejecución de update en C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cordial saludo equipo les pido el siguiente favor con lo siguiente referente a una instruccion sql 'Update' que no me sirve programándola en un botón en C# ASP.NET, el código es el siguiente:

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   string codalumno = TextBox1.Text, nombreal = TextBox2.Text, apellal = TextBox3.Text, sexal = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue, paisal = DropDownList1.SelectedValue, correoalu = TextBox6.Text, passwalu = TextBox7.Text, telefalu = TextBox8.Text, direalu = TextBox9.Text;
            double edadal = double.Parse(TextBox4.Text);
            DateTime fechnalal = DateTime.Parse(TextBox5.Text);
            connection.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Update alumnos set  nombreal='" + nombreal + "',apellal='" + apellal + "',sexal= '" + sexal + "',edadal= '" + edadal + ",fechnalal= '" + fechnalal + ", paisal='" + paisal + "',correoalu='" + correoalu + "',passwalu= '" + passwalu + "',telefalu='" + telefalu + "',direalu='" + direalu + "' where codalumno=" + codalumno + ")", connection);
            connection.Close();
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Actualizado satisfactoriamente');", true);
            GetEmployeeList();
        }
```

la funcion GetEmployeeList(); es para mostrar los registros de la tabla ya insertados dentro de la base de datos y el código es el siguiente:

```
   public void GetEmployeeList()
            {
     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from alumnos", connection);
                    SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dt);
     sd.Fill(dt);
    this.GridView1.DataSource = (dt);
      GridView1.DataBind(); 
             }
```

Muchas gracias por la colaboracion que me puedan brindar

Comment: Y... Cuál es el error?

Comment: Cordial saludo Arriel, antes quiero comentarle que ayer incluí la siguiente línea de código para que funcione bien todo:
                                 
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
Pero desafortunadamente me aparece el siguiente error:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '25'.'

Vale mencionar que este fragmento de código lo incluí por que me funciono bien con el Insert y con el Delete.

Si quito este fragmento de código: command.ExecuteNonQuery(); no me muestra ningún error pero no se actualiza el registro. 

Muchas gracias por cualquier colaboración!.

Comment: `+ "',edadal= '" + edadal + ",fechnalal= '" + fechnalal + "` te faltan las comillas simples de cierre de la sintaxis SQL. Recuerda que realizar queries donde reemplazas strings puede hacer tu aplicación vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Sugiero investigues acerca de ello y aprendas cómo mitigarlo